# I am Trying to crop the image after applying prespective transformation with min area of bounding rectangle

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to applying counter and then minimum area rectangle on    the markers image and i got the error that i mentioned in the end of    the implementation.  I tried to resolve the error by converting the    mask into gray scale image but it show's the same error This is the marker image that i used to create contour and then applying bounding box and after applying bounding box i am trying to apply perspective transformation for to remove the orientation problem in the original image

[image]

**Here is my implementation Details**

```py
                           i = 3
imagemask = np.zeros(markers.shape)
imagemask[markers==i]=255
dilation = cv2.dilate(imagemask,kernel=np.ones((5,5)),iterations = 3)
```

"Dilation for to increase the boundary on the RGB image"

```
#     coords = np.column_stack(np.where(imagemask  > 0))
# float_img = np.random.random((4,4))
im = np.array(dilation * 255, dtype = np.uint8)
```

"To remove the problem of 8UC1 problem"

```
contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(im,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

"To Draw the contour"

```
imgaftercounterboundary = cv2.drawContours(dilation, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
# plt.imshow(img,cmap= 'gray')
cnt = contours[0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
# img.shape
#    im = np.array(imagemask / 255, dtype = np.uint64) 
#   img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
imageafterBounding = cv2.rectangle(coffee_RGB,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), 
(0,255,0),2)
# rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
# box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
# box = np.int0(box)
# im = cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)

# Finding minimum Area
 rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
#print(rect)
 box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
# print(box)
 box = np.int0(box)
 x1 , y1 , w1 , d1 = cv2.boundingRect(box)

 print(x1 , y1 , w1 , d1)
 source =  np.float32(box)
 print(source)
 destination = np.float32([[0,0],[0, d1],[w1,d1],[w1,0]])
# print(x1,y1,w1,h1)  
# src[ : , 0] = [x1,y1]
# scr[ :  ,1] = [w1,h1]
# x , y , b , w = box.split()
 im = cv2.drawContours(imageafterBounding,[box],0,(200,0,2),2)

# plt.figure(figsize=(12,10)) 
# plt.imshow(im)
 M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source,destination)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(coffee_RGB,M,(300,300))
mask = dst 
finalImage = cv2.bitwise_and(coffee_RGB,coffee_RGB,mask = mask)
ptl.imshow(finalImage)
```

Problem is when i trying to mask the image from the original image it is show error .I mentioned the error below when i am trying to apply mask on the             image. i want to crop the original image and save it on some other place by             entering the  image description here applying mask on original image by using             the final image that i got after perspective transformation

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: ERROR :  error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'binary_op'

Comment: Print the whole error please, in which line you get the error?

Comment: I am getting error on  finalImage = cv2.bitwise_and(coffee_RGB,coffee_RGB,mask = mask)

Comment: what i am doing i have a image names as imageMask which is a threshold-ed image on HSV channel i am taking only one marker first i am trying to plotting boundary rectangle and then by using minarearectangle and after that i am trying to apply prospective tranformation for fixed the orienatation and the image that i got from prospective transformation i am masking with original image but it shows the error that i mentioned above.

Comment: Please copy/paste the whole error trace and edit it into the question

Comment: ERROR : error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'binary_op'

Comment: above mentioned trace is the only trace where i got the error

Comment: Why did you "and" coffee_RGB with itself? And I guess the size of mask is not the same as the size of coffee_RGB. Check their sizes before bitwise_and.

Comment: Can you please help me with an example of perspective transformation and then crop it using the result of prospective transformation